# How does :nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+8) select a range of elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

According to http://nthmaster.com/, when styling a range of elements by nth-child, we must do this:

```css
:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+8)
```

If we use only one `:nth-child()`, then we see that it styles all elements by that formula.

How does each of these two `:nth-child()` selectors cancel the other's influence on elements which are out of the range?

Answer (score 7):

Combining simple selectors in this way simply means you're looking for elements that match all of the given conditions simultaneously. Combining pseudo-classes is no different from combining other kinds of simple selector, for example `div.example` or `input[type="checkbox"]:checked`.

So `:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+8)` just means any element that is *both* `:nth-child(n+4)` and `:nth-child(-n+8)`. This can only be a subset of the matches of either selector when used alone.

And that is how you get a range of elements.

How do you tell which elements will be matched? Simple: look at the B in each An+B expression:

- `:nth-child(n+4)` matches children starting from the 4th (inclusive)
- `:nth-child(-n+8)` matches children up to and including the 8th

How this all works is already illustrated in the website that you link to, but the preceding examples use `:nth-child(n+6)` and `:nth-child(-n+9)` separately, which may be a little confusing. Here's a more consistent example to illustrate how the two selectors combine (ignore the `::before`/`::after`/`content` bits in the CSS — just focus on the output):

```css
li::before {
  content: 'li';
}

li:nth-child(n+4)::before {
  content: 'li:nth-child(n+4)';
}

li:nth-child(-n+8)::after {
  content: ':nth-child(-n+8)';
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```